# GRUB menu not loading after restart from Windows

Tags: grub2

I accidentally restored BIOS on my dell Inspiron 5559 which was dual booting earlier with Windows 10 and Ubuntu-16.04. After restoring BIOS, GRUB got deleted which I repaired using `boot-repair`. I restarted the system and GRUB successfully loaded. I wanted to make sure that windows was okay, so I booted into Windows.

The problem arose when I restarted from Windows. GRUB was nowhere to be seen after restarting from Windows.

Comment: @karel I actually used methods described on that page to repair GRUB.

Comment: Different approaches are suggested in the different answers to the possible duplicate question.  I'd suggest trying some of the solutions other than using `boot-repair`. If none of them work, edit the question to show exactly what you've tried along with the outcome for each attempt.